# Why are all routes asking for loaders?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, remix.run

I'm trying to set up a new Remix Project, and I'm trying to test nested routing, but every route I go to gives me the same error:

```
'You made a GET request to "/" but did not provide a `loader` for route "routes/Banking", so there is no way to handle the request.'
```

Here is my current setup:

- root.tsx

```
import type { LinksFunction } from "@remix-run/node";
import { Links, LiveReload, Outlet } from "@remix-run/react";

import stylesheet from "./tailwind.css";

export const links: LinksFunction = () => [
  { rel: "stylesheet", href: stylesheet },
];

export default function Root() {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <Links />
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
      </head>
      <body>
          <Outlet />
          <LiveReload />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

- routes/index.tsx

```
import { Outlet } from "@remix-run/react"
import { Navbar } from "~/routes/navbar/navbar"

export const Index = () => {
    return (
        <>
           <Navbar />
           <Outlet />
        </>
    )
}
```

- remix.config.js

```
/** @type {import('@remix-run/dev').AppConfig} */
module.exports = {
  tailwind: true,
  ignoredRouteFiles: ["**/.*"],
  // appDirectory: "app",
  // assetsBuildDirectory: "public/build",
  // serverBuildPath: "build/index.js",
  // publicPath: "/build/",
  serverModuleFormat: "cjs",
  future: {
    v2_dev: true,
    v2_errorBoundary: true,
    v2_headers: true,
    v2_meta: true,
    v2_normalizeFormMethod: true,
    v2_routeConvention: true,
  },
};
```

I've tried turning V2_routeConvention to false. I've tried using "index.tsx" and "_index.tsx".

Comment: You have to create your Routes so Links knows how and where to navigate.
  
Check this article https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. For me the solution was that I had left out the "default" in the function definition by mistake:

Original:

```
export function ComponentName() {
...
}
```

when I changed it to:

```
export default function ComponentName() {
...
}
```

It worked.

I wonder if you changed your definition to

```
export const function Index = () => { ...function logic };
export default Index; // export it this way.
```

it would work?

Comment: First of all the correct syntax is export const Index = () =>{...} 
not export function Index = () => {..} when your write functions like that.  
Your mistake is not the missing default keyword as you can export consts and functions with out default.  
You just importing with different way.  <br/>
Named export  
`export function Foo(){...} -----> import { Foo } from ...`    
  
Default export  
`export default function Foo(){...}  -----> import Foo from ...`  
check this article for more details https://javascript.info/import-export